# Brain centers vs areas (and how they relate to nuclei)

Tags: neuroscience, human-anatomy, brain, terminology, neuroanatomy

I'm looking for a reputable source that can provide succinct definitions differentiating the following terms in the central nervous system (CNS; particularly in the brain):

- **Area**
- **Center**
- **Nucleus**

Examples include [Wernicke's area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wernicke%27s_area), [piriform area](https://dictionary.apa.org/pyriform-area), [deglutition center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swallowing#Coordination_and_control),  [olivary nuclei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferior_olivary_nucleus), [vestibular nuclei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibular_nuclei), etc.

Really, I'm trying to corroborate my experiences having seen many examples of each but never having seen *official* definitions of either centers or areas. I know well that a **nucleus** is a cluster of cell bodies in the CNS [ex: [source](https://med.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Anatomy_and_Physiology/Book%3A_Anatomy_and_Physiology_(Boundless)/10%3A_Overview_of_the_Nervous_System/10.4%3A_Collections_of_Nervous_Tissue/10.4A%3A_Clusters_of_Neuronal_Cell_Bodies)]. I also feel as though **areas** are regions with functionally-related roles, and that they tend to be associated with the cerebral cortex. Centers seem to be deeper functional regions.

**What I'm not clear on is what the official differences between an *area* and a *center* are, whether (or to what degree) either term is inclusive vs exclusive of nuclei, and to what degree the relationship of all three words overlap either structurally or functionally.**

- I do know that Tortora & Derrickson (15th ed, 2017) indicate explicitly that certain centers are nuclei, but I'm not sure whether this more broadly describes all centers or is simply indicates a narrow example of a center.

> Examples of nuclei in the medulla ...include the cardiovascular center and medullary rhythmicity center.

---

<sup>Motivation: trying to find a reputable source to provide a simple definition for my students. I usually just run with broad explanations based on repeated exposure of each, but I think my students would appreciate a cited, specific definition of each term.</sup>

Comment: I think the answer is that ultimately there are no specific definitions of these terms, and likely some exception to any rule one can craft. That's a hard thing to cite, though. I'll hunt around and see what I find.

Comment: @Bryan I'm glad you said that. Because after teaching A&P for the last 10 years, I've never seen such formal definitions. Still, there must at least be some sort of first usage or something for guidance. Perhaps I'll explore this from a historical word usage perspective to see if I find anything more definitive

Comment: Anatomists are the enemies of formality. Thinking it over more, some things like "area" seem primarily used in neocortex, at least the examples I can think of, which probably denotes that those areas aren't discrete "nuclei" or anything but more of a vague region (given that aside from some subtle cytoarchitecture they're not histologically separate from other adjacent areas). "Center" may be the least well-defined of the group.

Comment: I am not aware of an official organization that handles neuroscientific terminology so I doubt you will get official answers. However, brain *areas* are defined based on some criterion, e.g. anatomical landmarks, cell density changes etc. *Nuclei* are usually clusters of neighbouring brain areas that often participate in a common brain function (e.g. auditory or visual thalamic nuclei). In my subfield of neuroscience, *center* is never used. I've heard it in cognitive neuroscience studies and is associated to me with an implication of functionality (e.g. the "fear" center).

Comment: If you want to provide your students with some explanation of what one of the terms means, perhaps you may consider the idea of discussing how and why they were proposed. The situation is relatively clear if you choose for example the Broadmann areas and you can find plenty of material. I have not seen any information on how/when/why the "nucleus" term was first used.

Comment: "Anatomists are the enemies of formality" One example about this are the basal ganglia, which are located in the CNS, so they should be called basal nuclei. The mistake is already settled down in the CNS nomenclature, although some people tried to name them basal nuclei (e.g. Haines, fundamental neuroscience)